# How will this equation imply PNT

Tags: analytic-number-theory

So we have $$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\Lambda (n)}{n}=\log{x}+C+o(1)$$ where $C$ is a constant, its partial summation is $$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\Lambda (n)}{n}=\frac{\psi(x)}{x}+\int_1^x \frac{\psi (t)}{t^2} dt$$ How should I go from here to prove that $\psi(x) \sim x$, which is a equivalent form of PNT.

Comment: I don't know. What makes you think it is possible to go from those two equations to $\psi(x)\sim x$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean $O(1)$ or $o(1)$ in your first equation? If the former, then (a) it doesn't make sense to include the $C$ term, since it can be absorbed into the error and (b) I don't think that estimate is strong enough to prove PNT.

If you mean $o(1)$, then see [my blog post](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/09/30/the-easy-parts-of-the-prime-number-theorem/), especially part 3.

Comment: FYI part 4. there includes $1/\log1$ summands.