# list of equivalence form of prime number theorem

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, big-list

I'm reading the book *Elementary Proof of Prime Number Theorem* and it gives several equivalence of PRT, namely,

> Three with similar expressions:
>
> (A1) $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\pi (x)\ln x}{x} =1$;
>
> (A2) $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\theta (x)}{x}=1$;
>
> (A3) $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\psi (x)}{x}=1$.

and three non-trivial ones with slightly different form:

> (B1) $M(x):=\sum_{n\le x}\mu (n)=o(x)$;
>
> (B2) $\sum_{n\le x}\frac{\mu (n)}{n}=o(1)$;
>
> (B3) $\sum_{n\le x}\frac{\Lambda (n)}{n}=\ln x-\gamma +o(1)$;
>
> (B4) $L(x):=\sum_{n\le x}\lambda (n)=o(x)$;
>
> (B5) $\int_1^\infty \frac{\psi (t)-t}{t^2}=-\gamma -1$.

By now, I can prove the equivalence of (A1), (A2), (A3) by Chebyshev inequality, and the proof of (B1), (B2), (B3) also gave in the previous book. I also proved (B4) $\Leftrightarrow$ (B1) using the so-called *hyperbolic summation method*. I havn't proved (B5) yet and posted it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984577/equivalent-form-of-prime-number-theorem).

Now I want to collect a big list about PNT's forms. Could anybody suggest some other non-trivial form of PNT? The statement as well as proof will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Almost everything is in [wiki/prime_number_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) and [wiki/Riemann_hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis)

Comment: And the analytic proof of the PNT is with $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros on $\sigma > 1- \frac{A}{\log |t|}$ for some $A$, and $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \mathcal{O}(\log^7 t)$ and $\zeta(s) = \mathcal{O}(\log t),\zeta'(s) = \mathcal{O}(\log^2 t)$ on $\sigma > 1- \frac{A}{\log |t|}$ as $t \to \infty$. See page 66 of Titchmarsh's book for how to finish the proof from this